# Let $abc =1$ and $a+b+c=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c.$ Show that at least one of the numbers $a,b,c$ is $1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $abc =1$ and $$a+b+c=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c.$$ Show that at least one of the numbers $a,b,c$ is $1$.

I tried to get a contradiction from letting $a<1<b \leqslant c$, but didn't get anywhere. What other approaches I could consider in order to show that one number from three is $1$?

Comment: Show $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=0$; then $a=1, b=1, $ and/or $c=1$

Answer (score 3):

If $abc=1$, then $a+b+c=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=abc\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)=bc+ac+ab$

and $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=abc-(ab+bc+ac)+(a+b+c)-1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: with $c = 1/(ab)$, show that
$$ a + b + c - \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \right) = \frac{(1-a)(1-b)(1-ab)}{\text{something}} $$

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: What is nice here? @VIVID This is unclear so -1

Comment: @Aqua What is unclear here?

Comment: What is clear except $c=1/(ab)$? No, steps! On a test a student would get 0 points if I would grade him/her.  @RobertIsrael

Comment: @Aqua with $c = 1/(ab)$, show that 
$$ a + b + c - \left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \right) = a+b+1/(ab)-1/a-1/b-ab=0$$
if $a=1$ then the expression is $0$, else if $b=1$ again $0$, else if $ab=1$ again $0$. Hence $(a-1)(b-1)(ab-1)$ divides the expression. Therefore,
$$...=(a-1)(b-1)(ab-1)\cdot \text{something}$$ This seems nice to me...

Comment: @Aqua I was providing a hint, not the full solution.  Of course the student should calculate what "something" is, namely $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

From [Show that at least one of the solution is $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344206/show-that-at-least-one-of-the-solution-is-1/2344218#2344218) (only visible for >10K users because the question has been deleted):

$a,b,c\,$ are the roots of $\,x^3-\lambda x^2+\lambda x-1=0\,$ where $\,\lambda=a+b+c=ab+bc+ca\,$.

Comment: Now this is nice!